# True positive, False positive, False Negative calculation data frame python

Tags: python, pandas, computer-vision, precision, object-detection

I have trained an object detection network. I have a ground truth annotation CSV in the format,
`filename, height, width, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, class`. When I score an input image, I get the output CSV in this format: `filename, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, class, confidence`.

I need to merge these data frames considering the `IoU`. SO basically the output dataframe should contain,

1. The ground truth and its corresponding prediction along with `IoU` value if a match is found
2. The ground truth values and Nan Prediction values if `IoU` match was not found
3. Nan ground truth values and prediction values if `IoU` match was not found.

This will be an intermediate step for calculating Precision and recall values.

I am just adding a very small sample dataframe as an example here, which tests for these conditions.

sample prediction:

```
        filename  xmin  ymin  xmax  ymax class  confidence
0  dummyfile.jpg  4060  2060  4214  2242    DR    0.999985
1  dummyfile.jpg  3599  1282  3732  1456    DR    0.999900
```

sample ground truth:

```
        filename  width  height class  xmin  xmax  ymin  ymax
0  dummyfile.jpg   7201    5400    DR  3598  3728  1279  1451
1  dummyfile.jpg   7201    5400    DR  3916  4038  2186  2274
```

Expected final output:

[image: final output]

I am adding my current approach as an answer. Is there any better way to achieve this? The data can be pretty large.

Comment: any faster solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach I found,

1. Defining IoU function:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

def IOU(df):
    '''funtion to calulcate IOU within rows of dataframe'''
    # determining the minimum and maximum -coordinates of the intersection rectangle
    xmin_inter = max(df.xmin, df.xmin_pred)
    ymin_inter = max(df.ymin, df.ymin_pred)
    xmax_inter = min(df.xmax, df.xmax_pred)
    ymax_inter = min(df.ymax, df.ymax_pred)

    # calculate area of intersection rectangle
    inter_area = max(0, xmax_inter - xmin_inter + 1) * max(0, ymax_inter - ymin_inter + 1)

    # calculate area of actual and predicted boxes
    actual_area = (df.xmax - df.xmin + 1) * (df.ymax - df.ymin + 1)
    pred_area = (df.xmax_pred - df.xmin_pred + 1) * (df.ymax_pred - df.ymin_pred+ 1)

    # computing intersection over union
    iou = inter_area / float(actual_area + pred_area - inter_area)

    # return the intersection over union value
    return iou
```

2. reading ground truth and prediction CSV

```py
ground_truth=pd.read_csv("sample_gt.csv")
prediction=pd.read_csv('sample_preds.csv')

###renaming prediction df columns with _pred suffix
pred_cols=prediction.columns.tolist()
pred_cols.remove('filename')
new_cols=[col+'_pred' for col in pred_cols ]
new_col_dict=dict(zip(pred_cols,new_cols))
prediction.rename(columns=new_col_dict,inplace=True)
```

3. Outer join ground truth and prediction

```py
###outer joining the prediciton and ground truth df
newdf=pd.merge(prediction,ground_truth,'outer',on='filename')

###applying iou calculation
newdf['iou']= newdf.apply(IOU, axis = 1)
###filtering all iou=0
newdf=newdf[newdf['iou']>0]
```

[image: IoU match]

4. getting non-match values from ground truth and prediction.

```py
final_df=pd.merge(prediction,newdf,on=prediction.columns.tolist(),how='left')
final_df=pd.merge(final_df,ground_truth,on=ground_truth.columns.tolist(),how='outer')
```

[image: final output]